# Is This the Correct Way to Open Windows in a WPF Project with MVVM Architecture?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am new to WPF and MVVM architecture and I need some guidance. I am working on a WPF project where I need to open different windows within the same project. I have seen a couple of posts on how to do this, but they are all from 2009-2011. I am wondering if these posts are still relevant or if there are new conventions on how to approach opening other windows in WPF with an MVVM architecture.

Here is what I have so far:

InfoDialog.xaml

```
<TabControl SelectionChanged="TabControl_SelectionChanged">
    <TabItem Name="InfoTab">
        <TabItem.Header>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="Images/info-icon.png" Width="16" Height="16" Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </TabItem.Header>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
private void TabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TabControl tabControl = sender as TabControl;
    TabItem selectedTab = tabControl.SelectedItem as TabItem;

    if (selectedTab.Name == "InfoTab")
    {
        NewWindow newWindow = new NewWindow();
        newWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

What is the correct way of doing this in an MVVM architecture WPF project? Also opening the windows doesn't have to be strictly through a TabItem.

Comment: You can create a service to manage windows and inject it into your ViewModel

Comment: This is the correct approach. Code-behind is the right place to handle views and view logic. It must not necessarily be code-behind but inside the View component in general (not View Model or Model).

Comment: Another valid MVVM solution is to us the view-model-first pattern. It's very efficient in displaying views dynamically while following the data first design principle. You would define the view models of your window control and allow the GUI to set a selected item (view model instance) the way you would bind an e.g. `ListBox.SelectedItem`. This logic is usually completely passive (as the view model must not contain UI related logic in terms of controlling the behavior of the UI). You can then create an implicit DataTemplate for each window data context.

Comment: An attached behavior can observe the SelectedContext property of a view model class and on change would launch the Window instance with the SelectedContext as the DataContext and Window.Content value. The Window.Content will trigger the Window to load the correct implicit DataTemplate to render the content. This last solution is mmore complex to implement but provides a convenient to use reusable solution. The code-behind solution is much less complex to implement and if you encapsulate the logic to load window instances, you can also make the code-behind solution highly reusable.

Answer (score 1):

What about third party framework?

I like using **Caliburn.Micro**, which support .NET 6, but you can use other frameworks [(Picking a New MVVM Framework - Moving from Caliburn Micro)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8E000zu8UhQ).

But if you stick with Caliburn.Micro, you can install it via nuget package, and can simple use it in ViewModel like this:

```
public class MainViewModel : Screen
{
    #region Constructors
    public MainViewModel(IWindowManager windowManager)
    {
        _windowManager = windowManager;
    }
    #endregion Constructor
    #region Properties
    private IWindowManager _windowManager;
    #endregion Properties
    #region Methods
    public async void AddMovie()
    {
        var viewModel = IoC.Get<AddMovieViewModel>();
        await _windowManager.ShowDialogAsync(viewModel); // or ShowWindowAsync(...)
    }
    #endregion Methods
}
```

For more information about `_windowManager` you can use/read this: [AddDialogToShellView](https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/Tutorials/WPF/AddDialogToShellView)

And how to "setup/run" the application you can read here: [The Bootstrapper class](https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/Tutorials/WPF/Bootstrapper) (don't forget to implement `SimpleContainer` and register ViewModels to use `IoC.Get<...ViewModel>`)

Calibro.Micro uses MIT license, so you can use it in [commercial use](https://www.google.com/search?q=MIT%20license%20commercial%20use).